# Postgresql - text Array to Json Array error

Tags: sql, arrays, json, string, postgresql

I am getting an error while trying to convert string array to json array in postgresql.

**SQL:**

> select * from

```
jsonb_array_elements_text(to_jsonb('[{\"Apr2021\":\"1.2\",\"Aug2000\":\"1.3\",\"Dec2023\":\"22.5\",\"Feb2023\":\"66.7\",\"Jan2023\":\"99.1\",\"Jul2023\":\"11.0\",\"Jun2021\":\"44.2\",\"Mar2023\":\"55\",\"May2023\":\"10\",\"Nov2023\":\"44\",\"Oct2023\":\"99\",\"Sep2023\":\"33\"}]'::json))
```

**Error:**

```
>  Invalid operation: invalid input syntax for type json  Details: Token
> "Apr2021" is invalid.
```

Comment: Skip the backslashes (\)

Comment: I am not able to remove backslashes . I have tried with replace(data, '\"', '"') still it doesn't works

Comment: The `replace()` does work:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d879e43594c0b77ab8f480c5bf3cd55b

Comment: 1) The original statement works for me. What version of Postgres? 2) Why `to_jsonb(...::json)` instead of just `jsonb_array_elements_text('[{ ....}]'::jsonb`? Add information as update to question. 3) Token  "Apr2021" is valid: `select '{\"Apr2021\": 2}'::jsonb; {"Apr2021": 2}`.

Comment: My postgres version is PostgreSQL 10.18.

Comment: It works in version 10 if you do: `select * from jsonb_array_elements_text(E'[{...}]::jsonb);`.

Comment: Turns out that the case that worked for me was on the one instance I had `standard_conforming_strings = off`. This reverted to old Postgres behavior where a '\' in a string was taken as an escape character.  In current versions `standard_conforming_strings = on` which is why the `E'..'` works as it causes the '\' to be seen as an escape in that string.